# i have added linked in company widget but its not resposive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, linkedin-api

i have linked in company widget but it not responsive it has fixed size how to make it responsive 
below is code i m using

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/CompanyProfile" data-id="505329" data-format="inline"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't give much information, so I apologize for the vague answer. The container for this class is `.container-outer` followed by `.li-profile-container .company`.

So you'd want add that to your stylesheet and make it responsive. Need examples of responsive web design? [Here ya go](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=responsive%20web%20design).

Comment: sunjewels.com see linked in widget at bottom

Comment: Use your developer console to see which classes need to be modified. Chrome you right click on the widget and select "inspect element". After that it's fairly self explanatory. If you need more help please post additional code.

Comment: done for that element but when is write css it doens't works

Comment: I checked the elements on your page and it looked like they are using different element names, so you'll have to use the developer options as I said in my above comment to get those element names to modify. You may have to add !important to the properties to prevent the script from overwriting those styles.

Comment: .container-outer followed by .li-profile-container .company. are there but seems not working does css works for iframe also??

Comment: Yes, it'd have to be referenced from the page called by the iframe or apply those styles using js - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe

Comment: could u provide easy solution getting difficulty with that

Comment: not working belwo code:<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/CompanyProfile" data-id="505329" data-format="inline" data-width="100px" ></script>

Comment: If you have control over the iframe then you'd be able to modify the CSS on the page that the iframe is calling. If not, you'd have to do something similar to the JS solution.

Comment: i tried js solution but it doesn not works

Comment: You need to post what you've tried so others can help you. StackOverflow is intended for helping people, not doing the work for them.